# tqdm progress bar and multiprocessing

Tags: python, multiprocessing, tqdm

I'm trying to add a progression bar to my program, however, solutions that seems to works for other (on other posts) do not work for me.

Python version 3.6.

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import tqdm

def f(dynamic, fix1, fix2):
    return dynamic + fix1 + fix2

N = 2

fix1 = 5
fix2= 10

dynamic = range(10)

p = mp.Pool(processes = N)

for _ in tqdm.tqdm(p.starmap(f, [(d, fix1, fix2) for d in dynamic]), total = len(dynamic)):
    pass

p.close()
p.join()
```

Any idea why the multiprocessing works (the computation is done), but there is no progress bar?

NB: The example above is dummy, my function are different.

**Other question: how can I interrupt properly a multiprocessing program? The <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> that I usually do in signle thread seems to pose some issues.**

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, tqdm is not working with starmap. You can use the following:

```
def f(args):
  arg1, arg2 = args
  ... do something with arg1, arg2 ...


for _ in tqdm.tqdm(pool.imap_unordered(f, zip(list_of_args, list_of_args2)), total=total):
    pass
```