# Showing tqdm progress bar while using Python multiprocessing

Tags: python, multiprocessing, progress, tqdm

I am trying to run some computationally heavy task using Python's `multiprocessing` library, and I would like to show a tqdm progress bar for each worker. Specifically, I would prefer to have this functionality for `multiprocessing.Process` workers or `multiprocessing.Pool` workers.

I am aware of the similar StackOverflow questions about this topic (see e.g. (1) [Multiprocessing : use tqdm to display a progress bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41920124/multiprocessing-use-tqdm-to-display-a-progress-bar), (2) [Show the progress of a Python multiprocessing pool imap_unordered call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5666576/show-the-progress-of-a-python-multiprocessing-pool-imap-unordered-call), (3) [tqdm progress bar and multiprocessing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50154204/tqdm-progress-bar-and-multiprocessing) ) but they all seem interested on showing one progress bar across all workers. I would like to show a progress bar for each worker.

Here is an example function, taking place of my computationally expensive function I would like to multiprocess:

```
from tqdm import notebook
import time
def foo2(id):
    total = 100
    with notebook.tqdm(total=total, position=id) as pbar:
        for _ in range(0, total, 5):
            pbar.update(5)
            time.sleep(0.1)
```

When I try this sequentially, I get the expected results: 5 progress bars filling up one after the other.

However, when I try to do this with `multiprocessing`, I get the desired speed-up, but no progress bars are displayed. This is true whether I use `Pool` workers or `Process` workers. Here is my sample code:

```
%%time
from multiprocessing import Pool
pool = Pool(5)
pool.map(foo2, range(5))
pool.close()
pool.join()
```

[Pool - no progress bars](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4A6hi.png)

Per the comments here (https://github.com/tqdm/tqdm/issues/407#issuecomment-322932800), I tried using several `ThreadPool` workers, and this strangely *was* able to produce the progress bars. However, for my situation, I would prefer to use `Pool` or `Process` workers with progress bars.

```
%%time
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool
pool = ThreadPool(5)
pool.map(foo2, range(5))
pool.close()
pool.join()
```

[ThreadPool - progress bars show!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wwSWG.png)

Hopefully someone can help me with this. I have tried just about everything I could think of. For reference, I am using Python `3.7.7` and tqdm `4.57.0`.

Comment: let me get this straight, you want 1 process for each progress bar and every progress bar should display accordingly with the assigned task?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I would like to run `N` processes and display `N` progress bars, each bar corresponding to its own particular process.

Comment: you need `N + 1` processes, `N` for the progress bars  and `1` for the sys.stdout that communicates with other `N` processes, in order to achieve what you want. that `single` process should always check for `the others` to see their `progress` and then, update to the screen. im not quite sure about that what im saying can be implemented, but you always have to be positive and try.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Since I provided short snippets of code, I am still looking for an answer that is able to address my specific situation. I believe the setup of this problem is fairly simple, yet the solution still eludes me. I have run out of possibilities to try, which is why I have posted my question here.

Comment: maybe this will help you: https://pypi.org/project/tqdm-multiprocess/.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if the question is still relevant, but you can easily do it using the [parallelbar](https://pypi.org/project/parallelbar/) library. Here is a simple example

```py
#pip install parallelbar
from parallelbar import progress_map
from math import radians, sin, cos

# toys example of computationally expensive function 
def cpu_bench(number):
    product = 1.0
    for elem in range(number):
        angle = radians(elem)
        product *= sin(angle)**2 + cos(angle)**2
    return product

if __name__=='__main__':
    tasks = [1000000 + i for i in range(100)]
    result = progress_map(cpu_bench, tasks, n_cpu=4, chunk_size=1, core_progress=True)
```

[image]

Comment: Small note that the `core_progress=True` keyword argument to `progress_map` isn't supported anymore. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Searching the issues posts on the main github page for `tqdm`, I found a hack that works for me, but it definitely feels like a "hack" instead of a true issue fix: https://github.com/tqdm/tqdm/issues/485#issuecomment-473338308

The new (working) code looks like:

```
from tqdm import notebook
import time
def foo2(id):
    total = 100
    print(' ', end='', flush=True)
    for _ in notebook.tqdm(range(0, total, 5)):
        time.sleep(0.1)
```

plus

```
%%time
pool = Pool(5)
#pool.map(foo2, range(5)) # this also works fine with the new hack
for i in range(5):
    pool.apply_async(foo2, args=(i,))
pool.close()
pool.join()
```